# Filter and Delete Data as per selection

Tags: vba, excel

Objective: Apply Filter > Select the last month data that is January, 2016 and then delete the only this data.

*Very Important* = The macro has to select the previous month and current date automatically and delete ONLY those data. Example in June the macro should be able to Filter all the data from Jan - May, 2016 and then delete it.

Not sure how can I get this, I tried DateSerial but even that's not working.

Important info: Data is from Column B-J, Header = B2-J2, Date: C2 and the Date format is Jan-2016.

What I've done so far is below:

```
Sub Reporting()

Sheets("DATA_INPUT").Select

With ActiveSheet
.AutoFilterMode = False
.Range("B2").AutoFilter
.Range("B2").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria2:="1/1/2016"
End With

Dim myRow As Range
Dim ToDel As Range
Dim mainRange As Range

Set mainRange = ActiveSheet.Range("B2:J3")

For Each myRow In mainRange.Rows
    If myRow.EntireRow.Hidden Then
        If ToDel Is Nothing Then
            Set ToDel = myRow
        Else
            Set ToDel = Union(ToDel, myRow)
        End If
    End If
Next

If Not ToDel Is Nothing Then
    ToDel.Delete
End If

End Sub
```

Upon running the above code the filter is applied but nothing is selected that is Jan-2016 and nothing is deleted. What I'm doing wrong over here? I've used several permutation and combination but this just can't seem to get straight.

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) so you would filter out the ones to be deleted, and then delete.  Also, you may need to mess about with your date a little, maybe dateserial(2016,1,1) not 100% on the date as cant see data.

Comment: Hi Nathan, Yes I did tried UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) but couldn't get it right. So i tried the above step. The date format is Jan-2016 through Format Cells option. However, the date is entered as 1/1/2016 format. Can you help me with UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got it. I guess perseverance paid off. Here is the code that got me the desired output:

```
Sheets("DATA_INPUT").Select

With ActiveSheet
.AutoFilterMode = False
.Range("B2:L2").AutoFilter
.Range("B2:L2").AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:="2016"
End With

Sheets("DATA_INPUT").Range("B2").CurrentRegion.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Areas(2).Columns(1).Cells(1, 1).Select

Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.EntireRow.Delete

End Sub
```

Note: I created two extra columns which get me Month(K2) and Year(L2). And I based the formula to filter on Year(L2). Thanks to everyone who helped me on this.

Comment: Good stuff, not 100%, but I think that can all be 1 line of code for the deletion part, so the 1st line, miss the 2nd then .Entirerow.Delete.  Sheets("DATA_INPUT").Range("B2").CurrentRegion.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Areas(2).Columns(1).Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).EntireRow.Delete

Answer (score -1):

May be your filter will be like this,

```
Dim Dt As Date

Dt = DateSerial(Year(Now), Month(Now), 1)

With ActiveSheet
.AutoFilterMode = False
.Range("B2").AutoFilter
.Range("B2").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=">" & Dt
End With
```

above code, will hide all data before this month (2/1/2016), and you will able to delete them.

Comment: This is the output I'm getting after just trying the above code (see the image).